# Why a really weak-correlated predictor variable might have significant coefficient in a multiple regression

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, multiple-regression

Just as what I described in the title, I have conducted a simple simulation in R:

```
aa = matrix(rnorm(100000), ncol = 10)
aa = data.frame(aa)

lg = lm(X1~., aa)
summary(lg)
cor(aa)
```

This might not be the case every time you run it, but give it a few tries and you will see the desired result. Obviously, the predictor variables are neither correlated to the target variable nor to each other. I just wonder how to interpret this intuitively and mathematically.

Comment: You should show what you get, not just provide code. Firstly, not everyone uses R, and even most people that do won't fire it up just to see what you're discussing. Please also ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably what you're looking at is the smallest p-value for a coefficient in the summary output and remarking on the fact that you regularly get one (and sometimes more than one) being significant at the 5% level.

Note that you're performing nine hypothesis tests (not counting the intercept). Because of the way you're generating the data, these tests should be essentially independent.

So what's the chance you see at least one p-value at or below $\alpha$ when the data are all independent with $k$ tests?

It's $1-(1-\alpha)^k$. For $\alpha=0.05$ and $k=9$ that's about 37%.

This is a well understood phenomenon. If you want your *overall* type I error rate (rather than your per-test error-rate) to be smaller than 37% in your example, you will need to use a smaller per-test significance level than 5%.

There's many many posts on this issue on site.
[Try tags like [`multiple-comparisons`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-comparisons) or [`bonferroni`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bonferroni) for example, and searches for [*familywise*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=familywise) or [*family-wise*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=family-wise). Those searches should give you enough other keywords to explore further.]